# What am I doing wrong regarding the use of Xlwings and Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, macos, xlwings

I am a physician from Colombia, and I have recently been learning the Python language and how to apply it in my career. I have been struggling for several days to understand an error, and I haven't been able to figure it out, so I'm here to ask for your help.

I am building a cost-effectiveness model for the treatment of obesity, and the first step is to establish a weight loss goal through code. The way I have structured it is that certain data is filled in the input section of an Excel sheet, and based on that data, the script defines a treatment goal (%TWL).

I have already completed the code, and when I run it in PyCharm, it works perfectly from a medical perspective, and I don't encounter any errors there. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Vic.png)

Now, what I want to do is, from the same Excel file where the information is being extracted to define the goal, when I run the script, I want the goal to be recorded in cell F2. I have achieved this as well.

The problem arises when I try to add a button in Excel that, when clicked, runs the script using Xlwings, and depending on the values entered in the input section (in the same Excel sheet), it updates the goal in cell F2.[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJV0n.png)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Error'

P.S.  I am using a MacBook Air M2.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def main ():
    # Cargar el archivo Excel
    ruta_archivo = "/FULL ROUTE/COBESE.xlsm"
    df = pd.read_excel(ruta_archivo, sheet_name='Input')

    # Antropometría
    antropometria_peso = df.loc[4, "C"]  # Peso en kg
    antropometria_talla = df.loc[5, "C"]  # Talla en metros
    print()
    print("Antropometría:")
    print(f"Peso: {antropometria_peso}, Talla: {antropometria_talla}")
    print()

    # Comorbilidades
    # Diabetes
    diabetes_diagnostico = df.loc[10, "C"] == "si"  # ¿El paciente tiene diabetes?
    diabetes_duracion = df.loc[11, "C"]  # Duración de la diabetes en años
    diabetes_num_medicamentos = df.loc[12, "C"]  # Número de medicamentos para diabetes
    diabetes_usa_insulina = df.loc[13, "C"] == "si"  # ¿El paciente usa insulina?
    print("Comorbilidades:")
    print(
        f"Diabetes: {diabetes_diagnostico}, Duración diabetes: {diabetes_duracion}, "
        f"Num. medicamentos diabetes: {diabetes_num_medicamentos}, Usa insulina: {diabetes_usa_insulina}"
    )

    # Hígado graso
    higado_graso_diagnostico = df.loc[24, "C"] == "si"  # ¿El paciente tiene hígado graso?
    higado_graso_grado = df.loc[25, "C"]  # Grado de hígado graso
    print(f"Hígado graso: {higado_graso_diagnostico}, Grado hígado graso: {higado_graso_grado}")

    # Hipertensión arterial (HTA)
    hta_diagnostico = df.loc[15, "C"] == "si"  # ¿El paciente tiene HTA?
    hta_num_medicamentos = df.loc[16, "C"]  # Número de medicamentos para HTA
    print(f"HTA: {hta_diagnostico}, Num. medicamentos HTA: {hta_num_medicamentos}")

    # Dislipidemia
    dislipidemia_diagnostico = df.loc[18, "C"] == "si"  # ¿El paciente tiene Dislipidemia?
    dislipidemia_num_medicamentos = df.loc[19, "C"]  # Número de medicamentos para Dislipidemia
    print(f"Dislipidemia: {dislipidemia_diagnostico}, Num. Medicamentos: {dislipidemia_num_medicamentos}")
    print()

    def clasificar_diabetes(duracion, num_medicamentos, usa_insulina):
        if duracion < 3 and num_medicamentos < 3 and not usa_insulina:
            return 'Leve'
        elif 3 <= duracion <= 5 and num_medicamentos >= 3 and not usa_insulina:
            return 'Moderada'
        elif duracion > 5 and num_medicamentos > 4 or usa_insulina:
            return 'Severa'
        else:
            return 'Sin clasificar'

    def clasificar_hta(num_medicamentos):
        if num_medicamentos <= 2:
            return 'Leve'
        elif 2 < num_medicamentos <= 4:
            return 'Moderada'
        elif num_medicamentos > 4:
            return 'Severa'
        else:
            return 'Sin clasificar'

    def clasificar_dislipidemia(num_medicamentos2):
        if num_medicamentos2 <= 2:
            return 'Leve'
        elif 2 < num_medicamentos2 <= 4:
            return 'Moderada'
        elif num_medicamentos2 > 4:
            return 'Severa'
        else:
            return 'Sin clasificar'

    # Clasificar pacientes por comorbilidades
    clasificacion_diabetes = ''
    clasificacion_hta = ''
    clasificacion_dislipidemia = ''

    if diabetes_diagnostico:
        clasificacion_diabetes = clasificar_diabetes(diabetes_duracion, diabetes_num_medicamentos,
                                                     diabetes_usa_insulina)

    if hta_diagnostico:
        clasificacion_hta = clasificar_hta(hta_num_medicamentos)

    if dislipidemia_diagnostico:
        clasificacion_dislipidemia = clasificar_dislipidemia(dislipidemia_num_medicamentos)

    # Cálculo de la meta de TWL
    def calcular_meta(peso, talla, diabetes, grado_higado_graso, hta, dislipidemia):

        # Convertir la severidad de la diabetes y la HTA en un número
        enfermedad_mapping = {'Leve': {'Diabetes': 10, 'HTA': 5, 'Dislipidemia': 5},
                              'Moderada': {'Diabetes': 20, 'HTA': 12.5, 'Dislipidemia': 5},
                              'Severa': {'Diabetes': 35, 'HTA': 20, 'Dislipidemia': 10}}

        diabetes_severidad = enfermedad_mapping.get(diabetes, {}).get('Diabetes', 0)
        hta_severidad = enfermedad_mapping.get(hta, {}).get('HTA', 0)
        dislipidemia_severidad = enfermedad_mapping.get(dislipidemia, {}).get('Dislipidemia', 0)

        # Verificar si los diagnósticos son True o False
        if not diabetes_diagnostico:
            diabetes_severidad = 0
        if not hta_severidad:
            hta_severidad = 0
        if not dislipidemia_diagnostico:
            dislipidemia_severidad = 0

        # Calcular el peso necesario para alcanzar un IMC de 30
        peso_objetivo_imc30 = 30 * (talla ** 2)

        # Calcular la meta de %TWL para alcanzar un IMC de 30
        twl_para_imc30 = ((peso - peso_objetivo_imc30) / peso) * 100

        # Mapear el grado de hígado graso a su correspondiente meta
        if not higado_graso_diagnostico:
            twl_para_higado_graso = 0
        else:
            higado_graso_mapping = {"Grado 1": 10, "Grado 2": 20, "Grado 3": 40}
            twl_para_higado_graso = higado_graso_mapping.get(grado_higado_graso, 0)

        # Escoger la meta más grande
        return max(twl_para_imc30, diabetes_severidad, twl_para_higado_graso, hta_severidad, dislipidemia_severidad)

    meta = calcular_meta(
        antropometria_peso,
        antropometria_talla,
        clasificacion_diabetes,
        higado_graso_grado,
        clasificacion_hta,
        clasificacion_dislipidemia
    )

    print(f"La meta de este paciente debe ser TWL: {meta:.2f}%.")
    print()

    # Obtén la aplicación Excel y abre el archivo
    app = xw.apps.active
    wb = app.books.open(ruta_archivo)

    # Selecciona la hoja de cálculo donde deseas escribir el resultado
    sheet = wb.sheets['Input']

    # Escribe el resultado en una celda específica formateado como cadena
    sheet.range('F2').value = "{:.2f}".format(meta).replace('.', ',')

    # Guarda los cambios y cierra el archivo
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
    app.quit()

# Llamar a la función main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the VBA COde:

```
 Public Sub Python()
    RunPython "import Error; Error.main ()"
 End Sub
```

I have already checked, and I have the latest version of Python installed. I have installed everything related to Xlwings, and I have the Excel add-in as well. I don't know what else to do.

I have tried everything, modifying the VBA, the main script, the file paths from the Excel tab. In other words, I have been trying for three days, searching here and there, watching YouTube videos, using Chat GPT, but I couldn't solve it. That's why I'm here, presenting my specific case in search of a solution.

I want to thank you in advance for your patience, as I am a beginner in Python and English is not my primary language. Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: The message suggests that the name of the Python file ("Error") cannot be found from where the Excel file is located.  You might need to check that the PYTHONPATH includes the directory of Error.py, or move the script to another location.  Your VBA code is calling `Error`, which will work if the directory of the script is either the same as the directory of the Excel file or is included in PYTHONPATH.  (PYTHONPATH is in the xlwings add-in ribbon in Excel).

Comment: Note; this is also case sensitive, even on windows. So given your vba code to call the python file is `"RunPython import Error; Error.main ()"` then ensure the Python file name is `'Error.py'` with the capital `E` and rest of the letters lower case.